# Может ли вирус включить андроид?

Tags: android, вирусы

Планшет был **полностью** выключен. Также выключены интернет/мобильная сеть.

Ночью услышал звук пришедшего уведомления. Может ли злоумышленник удалённо включить андроид, а после выключить?

Comment: нет, не сможет. .

Answer (score 2):

Если планшет полностью выключен и не подключен к зарядному устройству, то удаленно его включить невозможно. Для включения планшета необходимо физически нажать на кнопку питания.

Однако, в случае, если планшет был не выключен полностью, а находился в режиме ожидания (standby), то в зависимости от настроек планшета, возможно удаленное включение. Например, в некоторых устройствах есть функция "Wake-on-LAN", которая позволяет включить устройство по сигналу с сети.

Я могу представить, что если на планшете было установлено вредоносное ПО, то возможно удаленное управление им. В этом случае, злоумышленник может использовать уязвимости устройства, чтобы удаленно включить или выключить планшет. Но это крайне и крайне маловероятно.

В целом, удаленное включение или выключение планшета в обычных условиях маловероятно, но возможно в определенных ситуациях. Рекомендуется следить за настройками безопасности на своем устройстве и устанавливать только проверенное ПО, чтобы снизить риск взлома или удаленного управления устройством.